# Verify private key in signed XML with public key

Tags: javascript, xml, sign, verify, capicom

I use javascript to open CAPICOM store to choose certificate.
After that I export selected certificate, public key and private key of that certificate and put them in three hidden fields.

```
    var privateKey = certificates.Item(1).PrivateKey;
    var cert = certificates.Item(1);
    var publicKey = cert.PublicKey().EncodedKey.Value
```

When signing xml I used:

To take certificate

```
    Dim hideCertCapicom As String = Replace(HiddenCert.Value, " ", "+")
    Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(hideCertCapicom))
```

For defining private key I used

```
    Dim keyC As String = hideKey 

    Dim cspp As New CspParameters()
    cspp.KeyContainerName = keyC

    Dim tmpRsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp)
    tmpRsa.PersistKeyInCsp = True
```

This will successfully signed my xml.

For verifying xml I used:

```
    Dim hidePublicKey As String = HiddenPublicKey.Value

    Dim keyC As String = hidePublicKey

    Dim cspp As New CspParameters()
    cspp.KeyContainerName = keyC 

    Dim tmpRsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp)
    tmpRsa.PersistKeyInCsp = True
```

But this doesn't work. It works only if I use the private key again.

Is it good practice to sign and verify with the same private key or to do both with public key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sign with private key and verify the signature with public key, and I want to share with you.

In SignXml() function I exported public key from private key:

```
 Dim publicKey as String = tmpRsa.ToXmlString(False)
```

Then in the same function I call verifyXml() function:

```
 Dim verifySign As Boolean

 verifySign = VerifyXml(doc, publicKey)
```

In verifyXml() function I took public key on this way:

```
Public Function VerifyXml(Doc As XmlDocument, Key As String) As Boolean

 Dim tmpRsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
 tmpRsa.FromXmlString(Key)

 Dim signedXml As New SignedXml(Doc)

 Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature")

 If nodeList.Count <= 0 Then
    Throw New CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.")
 End If

 If nodeList.Count >= 2 Then
    Throw New CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.")
 End If

 signedXml.LoadXml(DirectCast(nodeList(0), XmlElement))

 Return signedXml.CheckSignature(tmpRsa)

End Function
```